# Getting mouse enter event on full panel c#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

So what i have is a panel that's programmatically filled with custom controls using DockStyle.Top.

What i need is for the panel to get focus somehow when mouse cursor enters the panel so that the user can use mousewheel to scroll the panel.

I don't really want to give each control a handler because there could be hundreds of controls.

One way could be checking for mouse position and check if the panel contains it, which would probably require an extra thread or mousehook but perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: There's a property `Tag`. You can bind one event handler to all of your panels and identify them with `Tag`. This in a case you need something advanced (I don't have any real-world example). Anyway, first argument of handler, contains sender `object sender` you can cast one `Panel myPanel = sender as Panel;`.

Comment: Create a single handler function. Inside the `InitializeComponent` function, assign the same handler to each control.

Comment: @PLB That wont work since the panel wont see the mouse since it's under the other controls.

Comment: @sgar91 That would still require having a "massive" loop everytime the panel is updated

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005854/net-c-sharp-mouseenter-listener-on-a-control-with-scrollbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may implement the `MouseDetector class` posted by [Amen Ayach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209153/amen-ayach) as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619097/674700) to a similar question and activate the form when the mouse hovers it:

```
void m_MouseMove(object sender, Point p)
{
    Point pt = this.PointToClient(p);
    if (this.ClientSize.Width >= pt.X &&
                    this.ClientSize.Height >= pt.Y &&
                    pt.X > 0 && pt.Y > 0)
    {
        this.Activate();
    }
}
```

You should also set the `Panel`'s `AutoScroll` value to `true`.

```
panel.AutoScroll = true;
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly fine with the exception of adding a timer, which is not too bad considering i can use a single instance for any focus i need, thanks! Don't know how i missed that.. even though i read the answer earlier :P